# How to bind this to MySQL QueryCallback?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, this

I'm using NodeJS and MySQL with the following class setup. I am grabbing a row from DB and then am going to assign properties/values to object. My issue is I'm not sure how to bind the "this" from the Provider object to the query callback.

```
class Provider {
    constructor(id){
        if(id){
            this.load(id);
        }
    }

    load(id){
        db.query("SELECT * FROM providers WHERE provider_id = " + id, function(err, res){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                // Here I'd like to have this refer to Provider and not query function
                console.log(this);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

I have tried:

```
let getById = db.query.bind(this);
```

But that doesn't seem to do the trick...

Comment: You need to bind a callback to this, not db.query. Use an arrow.

Comment: @EstusFlask How should I use an arrow function in this scenario? Would it be load = (id) => {} or inside the callback like (err, res) => {}?

Comment: @EstusFlask That worked. Thank you so much! I usually avoid arrow functions because they're not as readable for me, but I won't make that mistake again.

Comment: The 2nd should do the trick. Check the explanation in dupe question. Yes, the difference between regular and arrow functions is more than visual, they aren’t always interchangeable.